How to match against multiple comma separated strings and return another column back
My input1 consists on two different name categories and their corresponding name variations separated by a semicolon (;). NAME2 is a subcategory of NAME1.
input1 <- structure(list(NAME1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "J", "J", "M", "N"
), NAME1_VAR = c("AA; aa", "AA; aa", "AA; aa", "AA; aa", "JJ; jj", 
"JJ; jj", "MM; mmm; mm", ""), NAME2 = c("B", "D", "E", "I", "KL", 
"L", "", ""), NAME2_VAR = c("CB; CCB", "ED; EED", "", "ICH", 
"LK", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

head(input1)
    NAME1 NAME1_VAR  NAME2 NAME2_VAR
   <char>    <char> <char>    <char>
1:      A    AA; aa      B   CB; CCB
2:      A    AA; aa      D   ED; EED
3:      A    AA; aa      E          
4:      A    AA; aa      I       ICH
5:      J    JJ; jj     KL        LK
6:      J    JJ; jj      L  
        

My input2 consists in IDs and different OLD_NAME.
input2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, OLD_NAME = c("mmm", "M", "ED", "B", 
"A", "N", "LK")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

head(input2)
      ID OLD_NAME
   <int>   <char>
1:     1      mmm
2:     2        M
3:     3       ED
4:     4        B
5:     5        A
6:     6        N

These old names need to be matched to any of NAME2_VAR AND NAME2 and return NAME2, and the same with NAME1. Still taking into account that the names in NAME2 are subcategories in NAME1, so for some names there is no NAME2.
The output should look like this:
 head(output)
      ID OLD_NAME  NAME1  NAME2
   <int>   <char> <char> <char>
1:     1      mmm      M       
2:     2        M      M       
3:     3       ED      A      D
4:     4        B      A      B
5:     5        A      A       
6:     6        N      N       

I already tried unnesting the columns and trying to then group by NAME1 but I am not really getting there yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

Is it possible to have 2 matches? ie what if you had another row with NAME2 = B and NAME2_VAR = ED?

@Onyambu When grouping by NAME_1, each string in NAME_2 should be unique. But there is the possibility that a given NAME_2 belongs to multiple entries in NAME_1. For example if NAME_1 = J and NAME_2 = B in the same row.

I am asking about NAME2_VAR and NAME2. eg for exampe in output, ID=3 there is ED which is matched to NAME2 = D and NAME2_vAR = ED; EED. Now what if we had another NAME2 = B and NAME2_VAR = ED what would be the output for ID = 3

@Onyambu got ya!, then ID = 3  would get a second row, one with NAME_2 = B and the other one with NAME_2 = D. Both would have NAME_1 = A

in your output for ID =5, when OLD_NAME = A why isnt NAME2 = B, D, E, I??

@Onyambu because If it only matches a string in NAME_1 and none un NAME_2, NAME_2 should be just NA. In theory you are right and all other strings belong to NAME_1, but I wouldn't have this information explicitly.

But it is matching many rows of NAME1 which are all associated with NAME2.  Or is it hierarchical? whereby if matching NAME2, then output NAME1 but if matching NAME1, do not output NAME2?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

input2 %>%
   left_join(input1 %>%
   pivot_longer(ends_with('VAR'), values_to = 'OLD_NAME', names_to = NULL) %>% 
   separate_longer_delim(OLD_NAME, delim = regex('\\W+'))) %>%
   mutate(NAME2 = ifelse(is.na(NAME2), 
                 input1$NAME2[match(OLD_NAME, input1$NAME2)], NAME2),
          NAME1 =  ifelse(is.na(NAME1), 
                   input1$NAME1[match(NAME2, input1$NAME2)], NAME1), 
          NAME1 = ifelse(is.na(NAME1), OLD_NAME, NAME1))

      ID OLD_NAME  NAME1  NAME2
   <int>   <char> <char> <char>
1:     1      mmm      M       
2:     2        M      M   <NA>
3:     3       ED      A      D
4:     4        B      A      B
5:     5        A      A   <NA>
6:     6        N      N   <NA>
7:     7       LK      J     KL


Thanks a lot! Sadly there is still some fuzzy matching, where e.g. an OLD_NAME retrieves entries in NAME_1 that actually do not match.

@msug include those in your example
